# html email breaks 'when using float on table' in hotmail and outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email, hotmail

I have an HTML email that contains 'mini table' that float left on each other.

I am thus able to get two mini tables opposite each other; the mini table then stack up on each other.

It works perfectly in yahoo emails but crashes in **Hotmail**, **Outlook** and then on **mobile phones/tablets.**

Below is an example of how it looks in yahoo emails:

[image]

But this is how it looks in Outlook and Hotmail:

[image]

I have attached my code below

I used a dynamic PHP foreach loop to generate the data from the database.

```
foreach ($this->getMembers() as $user)

{ 


<td width='310' style='float:left'>
   <TABLE width='300'  border='0' colour='#FFFFFF' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='margin-left: 5px;  border: 1px solid #999999; float: left; margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px'>
    <TR>

    <TH ROWSPAN=5 width='150' height='150'>
          <a href='https://www.bab.com/profile'>
             <img src='https://www.bab.com />  
          </a> 
      </TH>
       <TD width='150'  >
        {$user->getFirstName()}&nbsp;&nbsp;(Aged: {$user->getActualAge()})
       </TD> 
    </TR>
    <TR height='30'>
       <TD >
          {$user->getCity()}
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR >
        <TD >
           22 Miles Away
        </TD>
    </TR>
   <TR >
      <TD>
         {$user->getNoYrsWorkExperience()} yrs exp
      </TD>
   </TR>
   <TR >
      <TD >
        Salary: &#163; {$user->getSalaryAmount()}/hr 
      </TD>
   </TR>
    <TR>
        <TH ROWSPAN=3 width='150' height='55'>
          <table height='55'>
              <tr height='38'>
                 <td>
                     <a href='https://www.baby.com/profile/{$user->getId()}'>
                         <img src='https://www.bab.com/htmlEmailsIcons/contactMe2.png' width='113' height='38'  />  
                     </a>
                  </td>
             </tr>
            <tr height='10'>
              <td>
                 <a href='https://www.bab.com/profile/{$user->getId()}'>
                      View My Profile
                 </a>
               </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
   </TH>
 </TR>
    <TR>
       <TD  align='center'>
          Available From:
        </TD> 
   </TR>
   <TR>
     <TD>
        {$this->availFrom()}- {$this->availTill()}
     </TD> 
</TR>
```

```
}
```

The above code is contained within a properly formatted HTML email. I did not enclose it for simplicity.

Would really appreciate some advice on why its breaking on hotmail.

Answer (score 0):

Probably won't solve the issue, but worth trying: All other parameters are inside single quotes, but "rowspan" for TH are not quoted at all.

Answer (score 0):

First off, do not use floats. Most email clients will not render them correctly. 
Use align instead, as you have on the cell housing 'Available From:'

Answer (score 0):

As stated - don't use float. Almost no support for it on any email clients.  Also noticed other issues with your code:

1. no end quote on image tag source
2. Don't use margin. Using Cellpadding or cellspacing is best, but can use TD padding.
3. put all css in longhand (eg - border-size: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color:#999999) it is more likely to be recognized and understand by email clients.
4. Not necessarily an error, but the extra whitespace in the tags. Should be  not .
5. No quotes around rowspan number

Below is the best I could come up with to help. Without more exact info into what is being put in the email, this is best I can do. I added an opening table tag and closing table tags to the code below:

```
    <table>
  <tr>

foreach ($this->getMembers() as $user)

{ 

<td width='310' align="left" style="padding-left:5px; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
   <TABLE width='300' align="left" border='0' color='#FFFFFF' bgcolor='#FFFFFF' style='border-size: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: #999999;'>
    <TR>

    <TH ROWSPAN="5" width='150' height='150'>
          <a href='https://www.bab.com/profile'>
             <img src='https://www.bab.com' />  
          </a> 
      </TH>
       <TD width='150'>
        {$user->getFirstName()}&nbsp;&nbsp;(Aged: {$user->getActualAge()})
       </TD> 
    </TR>
    <TR height='30'>
       <TD >
          {$user->getCity()}
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>
           22 Miles Away
        </TD>
    </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD>
         {$user->getNoYrsWorkExperience()} yrs exp
      </TD>
   </TR>
   <TR>
      <TD >
        Salary: &#163; {$user->getSalaryAmount()}/hr 
      </TD>
   </TR>
    <TR>
        <TH ROWSPAN="3" width='150' height='55'>
          <table height='55'>
              <tr height='38'>
                 <td>
                     <a href='https://www.baby.com/profile/{$user->getId()}'>
                         <img src='https://www.bab.com/htmlEmailsIcons/contactMe2.png' width='113' height='38'  />  
                     </a>
                  </td>
             </tr>
            <tr height='10'>
              <td>
                 <a href='https://www.bab.com/profile/{$user->getId()}'>
                      View My Profile
                 </a>
               </td>
            </tr>
      </table>
   </TH>
 </TR>
    <TR>
       <TD align='center'>
          Available From:
        </TD> 
   </TR>
   <TR>
     <TD>
        {$this->availFrom()}- {$this->availTill()}
     </TD> 
</TR>
</TABLE>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```